# Subnet IDs are only supported for Interface and GatewayLoadBalancer type VPC Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

Aws dynamoDb only supports `Gateway` endpoint but I am getting error while deployment saying:

```
Subnet IDs are only supported for Interface and GatewayLoadBalancer type VPC Endpoints. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter)
```

Is this a issue with subnet?

```
VpcEndpointSubnetIds:
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    Description: Select the subnet to associate with the VPC endpoint
    Default: 'subnet-039c1ac2c0925fe94,subnet-0e9267fe210b042da'

  VPCEndpointGateway:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId
        ServiceName: !Ref dynamoDbEndPointServiceName
        VpcEndpointType: Gateway
        PrivateDnsEnabled: true
        SubnetIds:
          -
            !Ref VpcEndpointSubnetIds
        SecurityGroupIds:
          -
            !Ref cacheSecurityGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

When crating VPCEndpoints the `SubnetIds` property is only supported by **Interface** and **Gateway Load Balancer** VPC endpoint types, for **Gateway** type you do not need this property, so you need to remove it:

```
  VPCEndpointGateway:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId
        ServiceName: !Ref dynamoDbEndPointServiceName
        VpcEndpointType: Gateway
        PrivateDnsEnabled: true
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref cacheSecurityGroup
```

For more information check the [AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html#aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint-properties) doc